# I am trying to fetch data from firestore and then convert the data into an array. the new array should be an observable

Tags: angular, web, google-cloud-firestore, angular-observable

I have a service where i have written a method to fetch data from friestore.

the method needs to return a observable.
The data is then converted and stored in another variable. 
I want to create an observable of the updated variable. How can i go about it.

I have tried creating observer using Subjects, ReplaySubjects and observables but i guess i am missing something.
But i get this errors :

> core.js:5847 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot
>   read property 'asObservable' of undefined

and

> core.js:5847 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'next' of undefined
>   the following is the code.

```
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, of, Subscriber, ReplaySubject, Subject} from 'rxjs';

export class ProductsService {

  public List : Product[] = [];
  public productListObservable :  Subject<Product[]>;

  private products(): Observable<Product[]> {

      //returns an observable of type Product[]

      this.firestoreService.getProductsList().subscribe((doc) =>{

        //Fetch data from firestore and 
        //create the new list with updated id's

        this.List = doc.docs.map(prodItem =>{
          let x = prodItem.data()
          let test = {};
          test['id']=prodItem.id;
          test['name'] = x['ProductName'];
          test['category'] = x['ProductCategory'];
          test['tags']= x['ProductTags'];
          test['specs'] = x['ProductSpecs'];
          test['inclusions'] = x['ProductInclusion'];
          test['shortDetails'] = x['ProductShortDetails'];
          test['description'] = x['ProductDescription'];
          test['pictures'] = x['ProductImages'];

          return test;
        })
        this.productListObservable.next(this.List);
     })

    return this.productListObservable.asObservable();

  }


public getProducts(): Observable<Product[]> {
    //var test = this.products();
    //test.subscribe(x =>{
    //  console.log(x);
    //})
    return this.products();
  }
```

In Component.html

```
   ngOnInit() {
    this.productsService.getProducts().subscribe(product => this.products = product);
  }
```

Comment: why do you want to keep a local array of values inside your service ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors you are getting are because you never actually created your subject object. You only declared it. You can change

```
public productListObservable :  Subject<Product[]>;
```

To

```
public productListObservable = new Subject<Product[]>();
```

Alternatively, the way the question is worded, it sounds like you don't even need this Subject at all. If you're just using it to return an Observable, you could instead make use of rxjs's [map](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/map) on your existing Observable. Something like:

```
private products(): Observable<Product[]> {

  //returns an observable of type Product[]

  return this.firestoreService.getProductsList().pipe(map(doc => {

    //Fetch data from firestore and 
    //create the new list with updated id's

    this.List = doc.docs.map(prodItem =>{
      let x = prodItem.data()
      let test = {};
      test['id']=prodItem.id;
      test['name'] = x['ProductName'];
      test['category'] = x['ProductCategory'];
      test['tags']= x['ProductTags'];
      test['specs'] = x['ProductSpecs'];
      test['inclusions'] = x['ProductInclusion'];
      test['shortDetails'] = x['ProductShortDetails'];
      test['description'] = x['ProductDescription'];
      test['pictures'] = x['ProductImages'];

      return test;
    });
    return this.List;
 });

}
```

Comment: yes i realised that. after writing it here... that was quite naive.. that i didnt check the initialization earlier. Thanks anyways.